# How to store the old passwords in database?

Tags: oracle, jsp

I would like to store the 6 previous password so that whenever user would like to change the password it first validate with the old passwords and return accordingly.

How i can store old password without adding any new column in database.

Any reference if possible.

Comment: So, you already have a table with password as an column. And still want to support password history. Without an additional column?

Comment: Where do you want to store the old passwords? client-side, server-side  within the application server or inside the database ? Conceptually,only the latter makes sense, but you apparently dismissed that option since you ruled out a new db column - why ?

Comment: there is column of password in database and if i add one more with the name of "Old passwords" and store all password with the delimiter can its possible or i have to add 6 column?

Comment: I want to store the passwords in database

Comment: One of the basic ideas in (relational) database design is to have but atomic ( = unstructured, indecomposable) data in columns. So the proper design would probably be the suggestion from @Raja's answer. It comes with the benefits of a variable memory horizon, possibly time-based expiry of password history, and easy maintenance.

Answer (score 3):

I assume the target of your question is to verify that the password is not reused. Therefore i suggest:

Create an additional history table with fields `ID`, `TIMESTAMP` and further data fields like `PASSWORD`.

```
create table USER_HIST (ID varchar2(20), TIMESTAMP date, PASSWORD varchar2(20));
```

Create an update trigger on your `USER` Table and insert an entry in `USER_HIST` whenever password is changed. Keep only last six entries by user.

```
create or replace trigger "PASSWORD_CHANGE"
before update on USER_TB
for each row
begin
    if :new.password <> :old.password then

      delete USER_HIST h where h.ID = :old.ID and h.TIMESTAMP = 
        (select min(TIMESTAMP) from user_hist u where u.ID = :old.ID 
         having count(*) >= 6);

      insert into USER_HIST (ID, TIMESTAMP, PASSWORD) values
                            (:old.ID, sysdate, :old.PASSWORD);
    end if;
end;
```

Add a constraint on your history table to verify that the password is never used before.

```
alter table USER_HIST add constraint pwd_is_not_reused UNIQUE (ID, PASSWORD);
```

Catch exception when user changes password.

Comment: This assumes that you're storing the password either in plaintext or encrypted format. Don't do this. It makes your table a goldmine for hackers, containing all passwords (or reversible encrypted passwords) any user has ever used

Answer (score 1):

You can insert multiple rows and pickup the recent one for current password.
For validation, you can check with the older records for history of passwords like in the below implementation.

<kbd>ID</kbd>    <kbd>USER_NAME</kbd><kbd>PASSWORD</kbd><kbd>UPDATE_DT</kbd>
<kbd>1</kbd>      <kbd>user1</kbd>             <kbd>password1</kbd>   <kbd>12/12/2015</kbd>    
<kbd>2</kbd>      <kbd>user1</kbd>             <kbd>password2</kbd>   <kbd>13/12/2015</kbd>    
<kbd>3</kbd>      <kbd>user1</kbd>             <kbd>password3</kbd>   <kbd>14/12/2015</kbd>

This is barely okay for school projects. However, If you are planning for a production level code, then I would suggest you to reconsider your database approach. And also dont store plain text passwords. Use a `salted hash` instead.

Comment: That will only match the OP's specs if the records containing db pwds already carry a date.

Comment: it is possible to use a delimiter for inserting the password like this?

User1       password1,password2....?

Comment: Yes you could use delimiters, But you will have to make sure you have enough space in your column for holding all the passwords. (i.e. `6 x max_length_of_one_password`). I will update my answer

Comment: is there any other procedure?

Comment: @HarshitWadhera Why do you want to complicate matters by storing the complete password history in a single value instead of putting each former password into its individual record? You won't save cpu time and the space saved (if any) is negligible for common data bases. Also seriously consider (if you haven't yet done so) not to store plaintext passwords but their encrypted counterparts - passwords having been used beyond the memory horizon tend to be reused when the system admits them again!

Answer (score 0):

The only way you should be storing passwords is through a salted hash with multiple rounds of hashing, with BCrypt being the most notable.

If your database system supports a verify function to test the new password against a hash, you can use it. Otherwise you'll have to query all bcrypt hashes from the database, and run `bcrypt_verify` through java.

But please, do not **EVER** store any password in plaintext in the database!!